# Cannot print binary tree with indentation

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have binary search tree

```
        c
    b      d
a             e
                  f
```

And I want to print

```
c
  b
    a
  d
    e
      f
```

The depth of each node is not saved. I tried:

```
typedef struct _bst_t 
{
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN];
    struct _bst_t *left;
    struct _bst_t *right;
} bst_t;

    void bst_print(bst_t *bst)
    {
        if (bst != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", bst->word);
            printf(" ");
            if (bst->left != NULL)
                bst_print(bst->left);
            if(bst->right != NULL)
                bst_print(bst->right);
        }
    }
```

How should I change this code?

Oh. i'm sorry depth of each node is not provided. should i make a new function to get depth of each node??

Comment: The question cannot be answered because there is not enough information. Please read this: [ask] and the [edit]  your question and show a [mcve].

Comment: Personally, I think there is enough code here to understand the problem though you should include what it displays currently to make life easier.

Comment: @waniwani Are all words have the same length?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow in this example, i used a, b,c,d,e,f, but bst_t->word is made to save words.
so it can be a word with different length.

Comment: Look at the answers below (they both say basically the same). You don't need function to get the depth of each node, the depth is implicitely know via the recursion depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive function needs to know the current depth so it can print the required number of spaces. This can be done by adding a `depth` parameter to the recursive function. Pass the current depth plus 1 in the recursive call.

To avoid adding an extra parameter to the main `bst_print` function, the recursive part can be moved to a helper function with the extra parameter set to 0 initially.

```
void bst_print_(bst_t *bst, unsigned int depth)
{
    if (bst != NULL)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("%s (%d)\n", bst->word, bst->count);
        if (bst->left != NULL)
            bst_print_(bst->left, depth + 1);
        if(bst->right != NULL)
            bst_print_(bst->right, depth + 1);
    }
}

void bst_print(bst_t *bst)
{
    bst_print_(bst, 0);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. 
if (bst->left != NULL)
            bst_print_(bst->left, depth + 1);
        if(bst->right != NULL)
            bst_print_(bst->right, depth + 1);

should be changed to

if (bst->left != NULL)
            bst_print2(bst->left, depth + 1);
        if(bst->right != NULL)
            bst_print2(bst->right, depth + 1);

problem was solved with this code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with the indentation (I think) and the solution is to carry the indent with you as you recurse.

1. Add a second parameter to `bst_print`. Either `void bst_print(bst_t *bst, int depth)`
   (purer, more generally useful) or `void bst_print(bst_t *bst, string indent)` (directly applicable to printing).
2. Each sub-call should add to the value:
   `bst_print(bst->left, depth+1);`